# Sci-fi movie about a girl whose classmates lock her in a room, because they were jealous that she was the only one of them who ever saw the Sun

Tags: story-identification, movie

What sci-fi movie has a girl who saw the Sun, but her classmates lock her in a room? From what I recall, she was the only one of them who ever saw the Sun, so they were jealous. During the short period when everyone is able to see the Sun, they lock her away.

It was sci-fi. I think they might have been on a space station, though I can't recall exactly. It was English language. I saw it in the 1990s, but it might have been considerably older. It had a very sad ending: she didn't get to see the Sun for another... year? Seven years? Something like that.

Comment: Welcome. What language was it in, when was it made approximately? Do you remember anything of the design style? - more importantly, in order to be on-topic here, is it in any way science-fiction or fantasy? Please tell us how.

Comment: Yes, it was sci-fi. I think they might have been on a space station, though I can't recall exactly. It was English language. I saw it in the 1990s, but it might have been considerably older. It had a very sad ending: she didn't get to see the sun for another... year? Seven years? Something like that.

Comment: Yes! That's it! Thank you, Jeff! I have been haunted by that film for 25+ years, and couldn't figure out the title!

Comment: @Valorum, because the film was based upon the short story.  Makes it a variation on the same work.  So I think it's valid to count them as duplicates.

Comment: @DavidW - OP hasn't confirmed which version is the one that they saw, hence we can't close them as dupes yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was called All Summer in a Day.

Answer (score 17):

Ray Bradbury's *[All Summer in a Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_Summer_in_a_Day)* has been adapted for television on several occasions. It sounds like you're referring here to the [1982 short film of the same name](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0195517/), directed by Ed Kaplan.

This version is from 2014, directed by Kody Cunningham.

The story is a popular choice for budding high-school filmmakers because all you need is a classroom full of kids, a watering can, a spotlight and a closet.